# Angular2 Routing with child tree

Tags: typescript, angular, routes

I'll start a new project in angular2 with typescript, but there are still some problems with routing:

I have entities like this:

- entity id:1

  - child id:1
  - child id:2
- entity id:2

  - child id:1
  - child id:2
  - child id:3
- entity id:3

  - child id:1

now i'm trying to code the routing like this:

*`@RouteConfig([ <br>
    {path: '/', component: EntityListComponent}, <br>
    {path: '/:id/...', name: 'Entity', component: EntityEditComponent}, <br>
    {path: '/:id/children', name: 'ChildList', component: ChildListComponent} <br>
    {path: '/:id/children/:childnumber', name: 'Child', component: ChildEditComponent}<br>
])`*

Of course, this will not work :-(.

How can I get parameters from entity to children, or how can i exactly configure this routing?

Thanks everybody,I hope you'll understand my problem.

Comment: If you are starting a new project, I suggest you use Angular2 RC4 and angular router v3.0.0-beta.2. The `RouteConfig` you have shown is way old, deprecated and not be used anymore.

Comment: Is there anyway a possibilty to configure the routes like that, also with router-deprecated?

Comment: There is, Remove last 2 paths from this RouterConfig, set RouteConfig on EntityEditComponent with the last 2 paths and it should work fine. But again use RC4 and routerv3. This v3 is easy and feature rich